# I need to set the JButton color almost in this way, Help:

Tags: java, user-interface

I am very new and I have no idea how to set the color in this same line of code, I need it to be this line because it is covered by a loop while or if there are other ways, I would appreciate it if you told me, thanks.

```
add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification"))),setBackground(Color.yellow)));
```

Comment: Split this up into several lines, they may all stay in the `while` loop!

Comment: can you give me an example? please? :)

Comment: Why do you use only one line of code? `while` loop can have a body in which you can create and fully set up your object as you need. if you already need a finished object - just make a method which makes one and returns it.

Comment: @Extibax see my answer for an example...

Comment: @deHaar I had not seen it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in an uncluttered way, use more lines than one and create every object needed in a single statement:

```
while (someConditionIsTrue) {
    // create a Person passing some parameters
    Person p = new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"),
            miResultSet.getString("identification"));
    // create a PersonAction with the recently created person as parameter
    PersonAction pa = new PersonAction(p);
    // create the JButton passing the PersonAction as parameter
    JButton jb = new JButton(pa);
    // set the background of the JButton
    jb.setBackground(Color.YELLOW)));
    // add it to wherever it is to be added
    someThing.add(jb);
}
```

This will make it much easier to read and debug…

Comment: Thank you! You're the best!, It will serve me well!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))).setBackground(Color.yellow));
```

You have not constructed jbutton properly, more over you have used comma to access property instead of dot operator.

Comment: that is something different than the actual problem, please post your code here so we can have a look at it to properly identify the issue

Comment: The problem was already solved above, Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this...

```
    while (miResultSet.next()) {
        Person person = new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification"));
        PersonAction action = new PersonAction(person);
        JButton actionButton = new JButton(action);
        actionButton.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        // set other properties if you need
        add(actionButton);
    }
```

P.S. I guess condition in while loop. Really - I don't know exacly.